# Meteor - Page refresh causes flicker when fetching data for router

Tags: javascript, meteor, iron-router

If I refresh a meteor page that is using a data query in the iron-router setup, the page loads the template but with no data, then shows the loading template, then shows the page with the data. I want to avoid the page flicker that is happening. This is my router code:

```
this.route('/stories/:_id', function () {
    if (!Meteor.user() && !Meteor.loggingIn()) {
        Router.go('home');
    } else {
      var story = Stories.findOne({ _id: this.params._id });
      this.render('showStory', { data: story });
    }
});
```

I've also tried this setup and moved the logged in validation to an onBeforeAction.

```
this.route('showStory', {
    path: '/stories/:_id',
    data: function () {
        return Stories.findOne({ _id: this.params._id });
    }
});
```

When I refresh the page with this setup, I see my 404 page, then the loading template, then the correct template with data.

Comment: Do you have loading template? and where do you put your subscriptions?

Comment: I have a loading template, and the subscriptions needed are in Router.configure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with this.

```
Router.map(function () {
  this.route('showStories', {
    path: '/stories/:_id',
    waitOn: function(){
        return Meteor.subscribe("Stories"); //we make de subscription here
    },
    data: function(){
      if(! Meteor.user()){
        this.render('/') //or sign-up template whatever template you want if user its not loged in
      }else{
return Stories.findOne({_id: this.params._id});
      }
    }
  });
});
```

Already Tested and its working